# Why do I have __stdcall?

Tags: c++

I am starting doing some directX programming. I am using this tutorial that I have found from the Internet.

I am just wondering why the CALLBACK has been defined as _stdcall and why WINAPI is as well.

I thought __stdcall was used when exporting functions that will be compiled as a dll.

However, as WindowProc and WINAPI will never been exported why are these functions declared as __stdcall?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
// WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, 
                            UINT message, 
                            WPARAM wParam, 
                            LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{

}
```

Comment: stdcall was historically used in WinAPI functions as default calling convention. I beleive it was even introduced by MS although I am not sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

__stdcall refers to the calling convention, and doesn't necessarily have to do with exporting functions.  Take a look at Wikipedia's article on [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) if you want to know more.  In brief, the compiler needs to know where to pass the parameters to your function, on the stack or in registers etc.

Comment: So it tells the compiler where to pass the parameters. However, If I don't add any calling convention, what will the  calling convention default to? Many thanks.

Comment: @robUK : that will depend on the compiler and its settings. Considering it's Windows, chances are you're using MSVC++ in which case the default calling convention is a single compiler option

Answer (score 6):

`__stdcall` also helps to reduce size of the code in general on the X86 architecture.  Instead of each calling instance restoring the stack, the stack is restored only once at the end of the function before it returns.

Export from a DLL can also be `__cdecl` just as long as it is declared that way.  For example: `wsprintf()` is not exported as `WINAPI`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that exports do not require __stdcall, only that the caller and callee agree (just like in non-exported functions). __stdcall is just what's normally used by convention.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it. The reason functions exported from a DLL has to have a fixed, known calling convention is so that users of the dll can call them. And likewise, with your WindowProc, it has to have a known calling convention so that Windows can call it. The same for WinMain. It has to be callable by the OS when it starts your program. :)

Comment: But on most compilation systems, you don't have to specify that - there is just one convention which everything uses.  It is only one platform that inflicts this stuff on the programmers - albeit, one that has a very dominant market share.

Comment: You could say that, or you could say that the Windows API just doesn't make any assumptions about the compiler. If they *didn't* specify the calling convention, and some compiler chose to use a different calling convention, your code would blow up. So the Windows API is just being explicit about how it expects these functions to be implemented.

Comment: In general, successful platforms are successful for a reason. It is impressive how well old software runs on modern Windows operating systems. You would do well to study the decisions of the leaders in any field.